# What is IF ELSE and ENDIF Directives in Assembly language? I am trying to make a program in which some conditon true message is show up

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86-16, masm

```
Dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

X db 89
z db ?

msg1 db "heloo$"


.code
main proc

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov z,offset x
;X=89
Y=-3
IF (z LT 0) OR (z GT 79)
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,9
int 21h
ENDIF

IF (Y LT 0)
lea dx,msg1
mov ah,9
int 21h
ENDIF 
   
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: Depending on the particular language, these are either conditional compilation directives or non-assembly extensions to the assembly language (both exist).  If you are trying to learn assembly and machine code, I would avoid these and use the traditional if-goto-label style of machine code: conditional and unconditional branching.

Comment: Use `cmp` instructions and then jump conditionally on the result.

Comment: `ifdef`, `else`, and `endif` are used to tell the assembler "I don't want this code in my program if a particular label isn't defined." It's typically used to have different versions of your program that run on different CPU versions, without the need to maintain two entirely separate source code documents.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the question, `if` `else` `endif` are assembly time conditionals that either include or exclude lines of assembly code. In Microsoft Masm (6.11 or later), `.if` `.else` `.endif` are run time conditionals. Link to Masm dot directives:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/directives-reference?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

In structured programming we have the if-then statement, which has a pattern like this:

```
if ( condition ) 
    then-part
```

In assembly language's if-goto-label style (while still in C) the same pattern is like this:

```
    if ( ! condition ) goto endIf1;
    then-part
endIf1:
```

In the if-goto-label style, we tell the program when to skip the then-part, as compared with C where we tell the program when to execute the then-part.  Thus, the condition for if-goto-label needs to be negated.

The construct `if ( condition ) goto endIf1;` is C's version of a conditional branch.  In assembly language that conditional branch is usually done as a compare & branch sequence.  For example:

```
if ( Y < 0 ) 
    print "hello"
```

becomes:

```
    if ( Y >= 0 ) goto endIf1;
    print "hello"
endIf1:
```

which becomes:

```
    cmp Y, 0
    jge endIf1
    lea dx, msg1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
endIf1:
```

Comment: In x86 assembly the conditional branch is called `jge`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an appropriate time to use `ifdef`:

```
CPU_8086 equ 1 ;comment this line out to enable "shr al,4"

PrintHex:
   push ax
   ifdef CPU_8086
      shr al,1
      shr al,1
      shr al,1
      shr al,1
   else
      shr al,4  ;original 8086 couldn't do this
   endif

   call PrintHexChar
   pop ax
PrintHexChar:
   and al,0Fh
   daa
   add al,0F0h
   adc al,40h
   mov ah,0Eh
   int 10h
   ret
```